# Concerning the ring of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, commutative-algebra, jacobian, real-algebraic-geometry

It is not difficult to check that the set of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is a ring (an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra),
and similarly (if I am not wrong), the set of continuous functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is a ring (an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra), where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, $a < b$,
denote it by $R_{[a,b]}$.

Let $R_{[0,1]}[X,Y]$ be the polynomial ring in $X$ and $Y$ over $R_{[0,1]}$.

Denote, for all $t \in [0,1]$: $f(t)=\sqrt{t}$, $g(t)=t$, $h(t)=1$, and let $A=fX+gY$, $W=hX+fY$

We have, $\operatorname{Jac}(A,W):=A_xW_y-A_yW_x=f^2-gh=t-t=0$.

Here, $W \notin R_{[0,1]}[A]$, since $W=hX+fY=\frac{1}{f}(fX+gY)=\frac{1}{f}A \notin R[A]$ (since $\frac{1}{f}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ is not defined for $0$).

However, $A$ does not have a Jacobian mate in $R_{[0,1]}[X,Y]$, since for every $B \in R_{[0,1]}[X,Y]$:
$\operatorname{Jac}(A,B)=fB_y-gB_x=fB_y-f^2B_x=f(B_y-fB_x) \notin R_{[0,1]}^{\times}$.

> **First question:** Does there exist $A,B,W \in R_{[0,1]}[X,Y]$ satisfting the following 3 conditions:
>
> **(1)**  $\operatorname{Jac}(A,W)=0$.
>
> **(2)** $W \notin R_{[0,1]}[A]$.
>
> **(3)** $\operatorname{Jac}(A,B) \in R_{[0,1]}^{\times}$.

Perhaps [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) may help? Perhaps [trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) may help?
It seems plausible that $A$ may not be linear, namely, $A$ will have total degree $>1$.

> **Second question:** What if we consider complex (analytic) functions instead of real continuous functions?
>
> **Third question, general case:** Replace those rings of functions by other rings.

The general case has one plausible easy answer, thanks to [Warning 1.1.17](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=wKJqqd8t8KUC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), adjusted to my question: Let $R:=\frac{\mathbb{Z}[t]}{(2t)}$, $R[X,Y]$, $A=X-\bar{t}X^2$, $B=Y$, $W=X$. 
We have:

**(1)** $\operatorname{Jac}(A,W)=(1-2\bar{t}X)0-01=10-01=0$.

**(2)** $W=X \notin R[X-\bar{t}X^2]$ from considerations of degrees.

**(3)** $\operatorname{Jac}(A,B)=1$.

Therefore, in the general case we should add a fourth condition:

**(4)** $R$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra.

Any hints and comments are welcome!